# Match whole strings instead of containing a string

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a macro which loops through a column and deletes anything in the array that I don't want. The problem is I want to keep certain cells that contain a "deletable string" but also contain other info.

**E.G:** If in my array of things to delete I have "VARO". I do not want to delete a cell with "VARO - summary", I just want to delete cells that only contain "VARO". Not sure what to change in my code to achieve this! any help on syntax and also on efficiency would be great as i'm still learning :)

```
Dim tDelete As Variant
Dim sKeep As String, x As Long
Dim rngSearch As Range, c As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long

tDelete = Array("ABEL", "VARO")
Dim delCell As Boolean
     For x = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 5 Step -1
         Set c = Range("A" & x).Cells
         delCell = False
         For j = LBound(tDelete) To UBound(tDelete)
             If InStr(c.value, tDelete(j)) Then
                 delCell = True
             End If
         Next j
         If deleteCell Then c.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
     Next x
```

My hunch is that the problem lies with the InStr function but I would not know how to change this!

**EDIT :** Thinking of using StrComp but not sure of the appropriate syntax. So in the IF Then could I have

```
If StrComp(c.value, tDelete(j))=0 Then
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there! If you use

```
IF StrComp(c.value, dontDelete(j),vbtextcompare) = 0 Then
```

This will find the exact cell match!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub check_this()
    Dim tDelete As Variant
    Dim sKeep As String, x As Long
    Dim rngSearch As Range, c As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    tDelete = Array("ABEL", "VARO")
    Dim delCell As Boolean
        For x = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 5 Step -1
            Set c = Range("A" & x).Cells
            delCell = False
            For j = LBound(tDelete) To UBound(tDelete)
                If c.Value = tDelete(j) Then
                    c.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
                End If
            Next j
        Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also make an AND statement such that "Varo" true and "Varo " (Space after Varo) False then delete.

Conversely you could check that the string contains "Varo" and the length of the string is also equal to the length of "Varo"  If those two cases are true then delete.

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT* How about just simply write:

```
If c.value = tDelete(j) Then
    ' delete the cell
```

This tests that it is an exact match, so cells with exactly "VARO" will be deleted but cells that contain "....VARO..." not.

Comment: If you can check that its a full match, why do you need to check for a partial match?  Just wondering what I am missing here, or perhaps I misunderstood what you mean by a full match.

Comment: @Forward-ed, The first test is only true when the match is exact; the second when it contains. But I now see he wants it the other way around. That makes it even simpler: just test for an exact match and delete it.